# How to automatically fulfill task on activity start?

Tags: java, android

I have a code that requires two edittexts, this information is used to display direction on a map. How can I submit this data automatically on activity start, without the need of a button.

Side question, is there a way to hide these edittexts? To prevent further manipulation by users.

Comment: If no data is in the EditTexts, then what are you submitting? If you don't need them, and what to hide them, then why have them at all? Why use EditTexts if you want to disable them?

Comment: The information in the EditText comes from the previous activity. It is transferred through intents.

Comment: Sure, but when you start the other activity, you can't access that other activity's views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditTexts can be either disabled using `editText.setEnabled(false);` or hidden using `editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`.

If you want to execute code on an activity start just write it into the `onCreate(...)` method.